# Appcelerator additional plist not attached to XCode project

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, appcelerator

I need to use an additional plist in my Appcelerator Alloy project, it's the plist from Firebase Cloud Messaging.

The plist is inside **app/platform/ios/**.

When compiling (I'm using CLI) the GoogleService-Info.plist is added in the build folder, however, when I open the project in Xcode the plist is not being displayed in the list of files, and when running the project in the emulator the Firebase SDK does not recognize the plist. 
If I add this plist with the Xcode interface and run the project in emulator the Firebase SDK recognizes the plist.

I'm creating a native iOS module to use Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK in the app.

Comment: Sorry man, i have not the answer but i can't wait for the module. Will it be available for Android too ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosSalinasOjeda Currently I only need to receive messages in iOS, I will not implement the various features of Firebase. If Android needs all these settings just to receive message I will be forced to implement. But I will certainly make it available in GitHub, the module can grow and gain other functionalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to insert GoogleService-info.plist into the Resources folder of the module. Now the SDK can identify the plist.